# Как добавить автоматическое переименование C# namespace в Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, namespace, visual-studio-2022

VS2022 по дефолту именует namespace так: название-проекта + относительный путь до файла. Я бы хотел, чтобы неймспейс был всегда только из названия проекта, например:

Пусть я хочу создать файл в проекте MyProject в директории MyFolder1/Folder2, тогда при добавлении нового файла, неймспейс будет следующий:

`MyProject.MyFolder1.Folder2`, а я хочу чтобы чтобы было просто `MyProject`. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Просто отредактируйте неймспейс и всё. Либо создать файл в корне и утащить потом в папку. Но вы хотите странного, неймспейсы по папкам - очень удобная фича.

Comment: @aepot У меня структура папок зачастую такая, что именуются по top-папке либо по названию проекта, мне не хочется элементы относящиеся к фиче именовать с разными неймспейсами т.к потом в тестах или каком-нибудь автомаппере получается 100500 юзингов + путанница где там какой класс лежит. Конечно можно вынести global using, но это так себе решение

Comment: @aepot вот например у меня проект называется CompanyName.Application.Contracts, там DTO/Interface, мне удобнее когда они все в одном неймспейсе CompanyName.Application.Contracts, а не когда каждая DTO/Interface в своём отдельном неймспейсе просто из-за существования папок

Comment: Есть расширения для Студии, которые неймспейсы фиксят. Например [NamespaceFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer2022). Вроде там можно свой формат задать.