# Автоматическое изменение namespace во всех вложенных файлах папки. Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, namespace, visual-studio-2022

При изменение имени папки в обозреватели решений Visual Studia 2022, у вложенных файлов остается старый namespace. И приходится входить в каждый файл, менять namespace на новый, чтобы он соответствовал папке, в которой лежит класс.
Как изменить namespace автоматически во всех вложенных файлах в переименованной папке?
Такая же ситуация, если я переношу из одной папки проекта в другую по 5-10 файлов. Как изменить namespace сразу у всех файлов в папке? Или возможно выделить сразу 5 - 10 файлов и изменить namespace в них?

Comment: [NamespaceFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer2022)

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1480174/373567